# Inner class overwriting class property

Tags: python

I have a Python script containing the following code:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    class Child:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

    def print_relationship(self):
        print(f'{self.name} is {self.Child.name}\'s parent')


myObj_1 = Parent('John')
myObj_1.Child.name = 'Steve'

myObj_2 = Parent('Stan')
myObj_2.Child.name = 'Oliver'

myObj_1.print_relationship()
myObj_2.print_relationship()
```

which returns:

> >>> John is Oliver's parent
>
> >>> Stan is Oliver's parent

but, I'm expecting the following results:

> >>> John is **Steve**'s parent
>
> >>> Stan is Oliver's parent

Is this an inheritance issue? Bad design? Both?

-edit- **Bad design** was the answer.

Comment: You are assigning a class variable, not instance variable. You don't instantiate child. The `self.name` isn't used.

Comment: `Child` is a class attribute of `Parent`, so there is only one such object in all of your code. But why would you use such a structure?

Comment: This is a generalized subset of a much larger code set. The inner class is being used to store information only pertinent to the parent class. I was previously storing everything in a dictionary, but thought I would expand my knowledge on Classes. Still working on that obviously.

Comment: Just because a class is only *used* by one class doesn't mean it should be *defined* in that class. Just define `Child` globally, unless the definition *itself* depends on part of `Parent`.

Comment: @gbeaven The child class should be at the module level, like the parent. And the parent should have an attribute which holds and instance of the child. So something like: `parent = Parent('John'); parent.child = Child('Steve')`, and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Child` represents children in general. Define it globally. Each instance of `Parent` should store a reference to an *instance* of `Child`. (That instance may not be unique; a child could have multiple parents.)

```
class Child:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Parent:
    def __init__(self, name, child=None):
        self.name = name
        self.child = child

    def print_relationship(self):
        print(f'{self.name} is {self.child.name}\'s parent')


oliver = Child('Oliver')
myObj_1 = Parent('John', Child('Steve'))
myObj_2 = Parent('Stan', oliver)
myObj_3 = Parent('Jane', oliver)

myObj_1.print_relationship()
myObj_2.print_relationship()
```

Of course, a parent could have multiple children:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, name, children=None):
        self.name = name
        if children is None:
            children = []
        self.children = children

    def print_relationship(self):
        for child in self.children:
            print(f'{self.name} is {child.name}\'s parent')


myObj1 = Parent('Bob', [Child('Alice'), Child('Chloe')])
```

Comment: aahhh... so you're just storing the `Child` object in the child attribute of the `Parent` object...

Comment: Exactly. Nested classes are not very common in Python at all. I won't claim to remember all the reasons to use nested classes in, say, Java, but I believe one of them involves the restriction of having only one "top-level" class per source file, a restriction that Python does not have.

Comment: much appreciated for the explanation and multiple children example as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the line`myObj_1.Child.name = 'Steve'`, you are creating a class attribute called `name` on `Child` class and assigning value of `Steve`. This name is different from the instance attribute in the line `self.name = name` which can only be accessed by instance of the class Child.

When `myObj_2.Child.name = 'Oliver'` gets executed, the value of class attribute `name` of `Child` class is changed.

In `print_relationship`, you are referring to `self.Child.name`, which refers to the class attribute `name` of Child class.